# RSpec with FactoryGirl/Bot - undefined method 'user' on model that belongs to user through has_many :through

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Trying to get into proper testing and figure out the ins and outs of basic RSpec with FactoryBot.

NOTE: The validation tests all passed previously and they're in the model files. I've just removed them for the sake of reducing clutter.

**My models:**

```
models/user.rb

has_many :fulfillments
has_many :milestones, through: :fulfillments


models/fulfillment.rb

has_many :milestones
belongs_to :user


models/milestone.rb

belongs_to :fulfillments
```

**My Factories:**

spec/factories/users.rb

```
require 'faker'

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name  Faker::Name.first_name
    last_name  Faker::Name.last_name
    preferred_name  Faker::Name.first_name
    username  Faker::Internet.user_name
    email  Faker::Internet.email
    password  'password123'
    password_confirmation  'password123'

    factory :user_with_fulfillments do
      transient do
        fulfillments_count 3
       end

      after(:create) do |user, e|
        create_list(:fulfillment_with_milestones, e.fulfillments_count, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

spec/factories/fulfillments.rb

```
require 'faker'

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :fulfillment do
    title Faker::Lorem.words.join(' ')
    description Faker::Lorem.sentences.join(' ')
    promise Faker::Lorem.sentence
    reason Faker::Lorem.sentence
    association :user, factory: :user_with_fulfillments

    trait :userless do
      user nil
    end

    factory :fulfillment_with_milestones do
      transient do
        milestones_count 2
      end

      after(:create) do |fulfillment, e|
        create_list(:milestone, e.milestones_count, fulfillment: fulfillment)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

spec/factories/milestones.rb

```
require 'faker'

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :milestone do
    title Faker::Lorem.words.join(' ')
    criteria Faker::Lorem.sentences.join("\n")
    reason Faker::Lorem.sentence    
    deadline Faker::Date.forward(30)

    association :fulfillment, factory: :fulfillment_with_milestones
  end
end
```

**One test that's giving me trouble (spec/models/milestone.rb)**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Milestone, type: :model do

  it 'has a valid factory' do
    expect(create(:milestone)).to be_valid
  end

  it 'validates attributes correctly' do
    should validate_presence_of :fulfillment
    should validate_presence_of :title
    should validate_presence_of :criteria
  end

end
```

**Error I'm getting in ANY test that involves the milestones factory**

Failures:

```
  1) Fulfillment has a valid factory
 Failure/Error: create_list(:milestone, e.milestones_count, fulfillment: fulfillment)

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user' for #<Milestone:0x00007f844d54f1b8>
 # ./spec/factories/fulfillments.rb:22:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/factories/users.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/models/fulfillment_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Milestone has a valid factory
 Failure/Error: expect(create(:milestone)).to be_valid

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user' for #<Milestone:0x00007f844d8d0b98>
 # ./spec/models/milestone_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Milestone validates attributes correctly
 Failure/Error: should validate_presence_of :fulfillment

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user' for #<Milestone:0x00007f8450829700>
 # ./spec/models/milestone_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User can have fulfillments and milestones
 Failure/Error: create_list(:milestone, e.milestones_count, fulfillment: fulfillment)

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user' for #<Milestone:0x00007f8450b7b9d0>
 # ./spec/factories/fulfillments.rb:22:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/factories/users.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.26253 seconds (files took 5.19 seconds to load)
```

9 examples, 4 failures, 1 pending

```
Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/fulfillment_spec.rb:5 # Fulfillment has a valid factory
rspec ./spec/models/milestone_spec.rb:5 # Milestone has a valid factory
rspec ./spec/models/milestone_spec.rb:9 # Milestone validates attributes correctly
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:28 # User can have fulfillments and milestones
```

Mostly confused because I'm not sure where or why it's trying to call #user on an instance of Milestone. The factories create Fulfillments for a User, then Milestones for the Fulfillments.

PS: It's my first time posting to StackOverflow (I usually manage to find answers to my really simple questions) so feel free to let me know if there's anything I could do to make future questions clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define classes explicitly in your factories so that they are not guessed but known.

```
factory :user, class: User
```

and

```
factory :fulfillment, class: FulFillment
```

Comment: Tried it, but I still get the same error :/

Side note: The syntax turned out to be

    factory :user, class: User

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I'm an idiot. I had a

```
validates :user, :presence
```

on my **Milestone** model. No wonder why it was trying to call milestone.user

Forget this ever happened please. ]: